# iTunes Match and Apple Music interfering with eachother

Tags: itunes, music, itunes-match

I have iTunes Match and I have got 6 months of Apple Music for free. But now when I try to play a song on an album that is also on Apple Music it will fail after 15seconds. I tried everything from signout to removing it from the autorized devices. But it's still happening. When I play these songs via Apple Music it will play the whole song. It's like Apple Music is interfering with my iTunes Match